# Sql query for table with product id and several values for that id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I apologize for the title but I didnt't know how to explain better in a few words my problem.
I have a table with car id, property id and value of the property.
Something like that:

```
 CarID | propertyID | propertyValue
    1        1            black
    1        2            diesel
    1        3            automatic gear
    1        4            80 kW
    2        1            blue
    2        2            gasoline
    2        3            manual gear
    2        4            120 kw
    3        1            blue
    3        2            gasoline
    3        3            manual gear
    3        4            90 kw
```

I can't get a valid query to get a car with property value for example black and automatic gear and diesel.
I tried with intersect and union but without result.

```
select distinct t.*
from table t
where value ilike 'blue' 
intersect select t.*
from table t
where value ilike 'manual gear' 
union  select t.*
from table t
where value ilike '90 kw'
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Edit: I must apologize again but I forgot to add more info. I added the case when all properties are the same except power and I want to get the car with 90 kw.
The database is PostgreSQL. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @pep, shouldn't you include the propertyID in your question as well?

Comment: What database are you using? You specified a lot in the tags.

Comment: @SandPiper The Postgres tag implicitly include plain SQL...the OP is using Postgres unless he tells us otherwise.

Comment: When I left the comment he had three completely different databases tagged.

Comment: @SandPiper My mistake, I thought you were new to the site and didn't read the tags :-)

Comment: @OtoShavadze I don't know why you deleted your answer, but I voted to undelete it.  Nothing wrong with multiple approaches.

Comment: @pep your new question can be answered directly using the already provided answer. What is the problem this time? And why do you keep ignoring the `PropertyID` value?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Just because your answer contains both approaches (only CarID and entire records also), I think my answer was just unnecessary here.

Comment: @OtoShavadze your answer was yet another way to approach the problem, not a part of Tim's answer... Perhaps you should reconsider undeleting it! Anyway, this is not supposed to be a competition where only the best survives, a multitude of answers can benefit the community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One canonical way of achieving what you want is to aggregate by `CarID`, retaining only records having the properties you want, then check to make sure that the distinct count of properties matches all the ones in your desired list.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT CarID
    FROM table
    WHERE propertyValue IN ('black', 'automatic gear', 'diesel')
    GROUP BY CarID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT propertyValue) = 3
)
SELECT * FROM cte
```

If you want to instead return all of a matching car's records, and all its columns, then you can use the CTE as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM table t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.CarID = t2.CarID
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Great answer! It depends on the assumption though that the propertyValues are unique across propertyIDs. What if propertyValue = 'black' can be a value for both propertyID = 1 (standing for Color) and propertyID = 2 (standing for WheelColor)?

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis The `propertyID` has nothing to do with this query, and I don't follow your logic.

Comment: I mean that the query as it is now asks something like "find cars which have any property with value black and any property with value automatic gear ', when it should actually be 'find cars which have the **color** property with value black and the **gear** property with value automatic gear". Of course  the question itself misses this point, so it makes sense that the answers do as well.

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis I see it now, good catch.  Yes, perhaps we should be checking key/value pairs, not just values.  But the OP's table and initial attempt shows no sign of this being needed/happening.

Comment: I asked him too, I believe it is something missing from the question (it can't be right...) But the remedy is very simple: `WHERE (PropertyId, Value) IN ((1,'black'), (3,'automatic gear'), (2,'diesel'))`. What do you think?

Comment: I think you're right, but I'll wait for feedback.  This could be a homework question where the keys don't really matter.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest reason you are having difficulties here is you have set up your table poorly and are not taking advantage of relational databases' full potential. Instead of a table that has fields

```
CarID | propertyID | propertyValue
```

You should have

```
CarID | Color | FuelType | TransmissionType
```

Then your query is much simpler:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE  Color LIKE 'black' 
AND FuelType LIKE 'diesel' 
AND TransmissionType LIKE 'auto'
```

I know it is an answer that departs from your existing setup, but if you modify your table as recommended you will make your life considerably easier.

**EDIT**

I came up with a different approach for you based on your existing table structure. Use a WITH statement to reform your table into a better designed one by selecting your primary key, then using subqueries to join on the same table for each individual property value. Then, select from that:

```
WITH newtable AS (
SELECT ot.CarID, p1.propertyValue AS CarColor, p2.propertyValue AS FuelType, 
    p3.propertyValue AS TransType, p4.propertyValue AS EnginePower
FROM oldtable ot
LEFT JOIN (SELECT CarID, propertyValue FROM oldtable WHERE propertyID = 1) p1
    ON p1.CarID = ot.CarID 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT CarID, propertyValue FROM oldtable WHERE propertyID = 2) p2
    ON p2.CarID = ot.CarID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT CarID, propertyValue FROM oldtable WHERE propertyID = 3) p3
    ON p3.CarID = ot.CarID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT CarID, propertyValue FROM oldtable WHERE propertyID = 4) p4
    ON p4.CarID = ot.CarID)
SELECT * FROM newtable
WHERE CarColor LIKE 'blue' AND TransType LIKE 'manual' AND EnginePower LIKE '90 KW'
ORDER BY CarID
```

Comment: i am upvoting, although this is not an answer to the question per se. Great pain comes usually with such design decisions, but almost always it is experienced too late!

Comment: I had an epiphany last night about how to solve this problem, so I modified my answer.

Comment: I'm aware of that the database structure isn't good but the reason is very good. The idea is to allow the client to insert propertyValues as he needs. Today it's the color of the car, tomorrow maybe navigation. Thanks for your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

One way

```
select * from (
    select your_table.*, count(*) over(partition by CarID) property_cnt 
    from your_table where propertyValue in ('black', 'diesel', 'automatic gear' )
) t where property_cnt = 3
```

Comment: Here is a [demo](http://rextester.com/JNRZK2103) you can use.  Not sure if the OP wants to return all records, though it certainly doesn't hurt.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - You mean "all records" or "all columns"?

Comment: oh, you mean that op wants just one row with value `1` (CarID) in this case ?

Comment: Yes, this is what I read, though perhaps I'm wrong.  I've updated my answer to cover both cases (using a different approach than what you used...no poaching here ^ ^).

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, you could indeed take your result with an `intersect` query as follows:

```
select t.CarID
from t
where propertyID = 1 and propertyValue = 'blue' 
intersect 
select t.CarID
from t
where propertyID = 3 and propertyValue = 'manual gear' 
intersect  
select t.CarID
from t
where propertyID = 4 and propertyValue = '90 kW'
```

Your own query's primary problem is that your SQL reads `from table t` instead of `from t`. Moreover you introduce a `union` instead of continuously using `intersect`.

Finally, I added `propertyID` to my query, please read the comments under Tim's answer if you don't understand why.

Having said that, I still prefer Tim's answer for your problem setup and support almost fully the design objections raised by SandPiper.

Answer (score 0):

> valid query to get a car with property value for example black and automatic gear and diesel

If we want cars that have color = black, transmission = automatic gear & fuel type = diesel, where, *inferring from the sample data* color, transmission  & fuel type have property IDs 1, 2 & 3 respectively

Then we could employ json aggregation on the cars' properties & check that our filter conditions are a subset to the car's properties.

```
SELECT 
  "CarID"
, JSONB_OBJECT_AGG("propertyID", "propertyValue") properties
FROM cars
GROUP BY 1
HAVING JSONB_OBJECT_AGG("propertyID", "propertyValue") @> '{"1":"black"}'::JSONB
```

This is valid in posgresql 9.4+. It returns the `CarID` that matches the key & value filters specified in the `HAVING` clause. It is possible to discard the `properties` column if you only need the `CarID`

We can also achieve the same using Array Aggregation & a `HAVING` comparison like this. Arrays have been in postgres for a very long time & the contains operator `@>` has also been in postgres for a very long time. This should work on all recent postgresql versions.

```
SELECT 
  "CarID"
, ARRAY_AGG(("propertyID"::INT, "propertyValue"::TEXT)) properties
FROM cars
GROUP BY 1
HAVING ARRAY_AGG(("propertyID", "propertyValue")) @> ARRAY[(1::INT,'black'::TEXT),(2,'diesel'::TEXT),(3,'automatic gear'::TEXT)];
```